# Which measure of Central Tendency should I choose for skewed data?

Tags: median, mode

I am trying to find out the best measure of central tendency from a list of data. As a first step, I'm trying to figure out the outliers in my distribution by using the usual Q1,Q3 and IQR formulas.

My IQR is 157 (which means there is a lot of variability in the data). My lower outlier bound is -170 and the upper bound sits at 459.

My question is: Since this is a skewed distribution, should I choose the mode or the median as the measure that will best represent my data set?

As a side note, what I am trying to figure out is the average booking lead time of guests (in days) from a particular market in a hotel. My data set is made up of figures from November 2013 to September 2014.

Comment: 1. When you say "average" what do you actually mean?  2. How can lead time be -170?

Comment: The average is the average (i.e. mean). Nothing obliges you to choose one measure and it is always sensible to plot the data and to calculate two or more measures, relating them to a plot. Reversing the argument, if mean, median and mode all agreed, there would be no choice to make. If they give rather different results they are each telling you something different about the data. Depending on your market and hotel, the mode could just be 0 (people turn up without booking or book same day) or 1 day (day before), which could mean a different clientele from those who plan some time in advance.

Comment: @Glen_b I guess what is meant is that (lower quartile $- 1.5$ IQR) yields $-170$, i.e. there are no low outliers, as would be expected from a (very) right-skewed distribution.

Comment: @NickCox Ah, yes, thanks now you say it, clearly that's what is meant. Sometimes I have blind spots.

Comment: @Glen_b Sometimes we **all** have blind spots. Looking at it again: the limits are given as $459$ and $-170$ and the IQR as $157$ so the criterion being used is based on steps of $2$ IQR away from the quartiles ($629 / 157 \approx 4$).

Comment: @NickCox Mean is giving me 149, Median is at 140 and Mode is 182

Comment: Mode 182! A minor mode at 6 months ahead? Please show us  the data if you can.

Comment: @NickCox It's data set made up of 1,306 numbers! How can I post it here?

Comment: It's sufficient for us to see 400 or so frequencies. Copy and paste? Website or URL?

Comment: @Nick Actually, this method sounds conventional: *fences* of $1.5$ (not $2$) IQRs are erected both above and below the quartiles, whence the two fences must be $1.5+1.5+1=4$ IQRs apart. Indeed, $459-(-170)=629= 4\times 157$ (to within rounding error), as stated.

Comment: @Whuber Thanks for the gentle and totally deserved correction.